# how to hidden in URL when default language is "en" and language selection should appear in other languages ? ( nextjs 13 app dir )

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13

default language is "en" if this language is selected it should be hidden in URL and language selection should appear in other languages.

this code here

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-i18n-routing

middleware.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

import { i18n } from './i18n-config'

import { match as matchLocale } from '@formatjs/intl-localematcher' //npm i 
import Negotiator from 'negotiator' // npm i

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  // Negotiator expects plain object so we need to transform headers
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {}
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales

  // Use negotiator and intl-localematcher to get best locale
  let languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages(
    locales
  )

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale)
  
  return locale
}

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname

  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  )

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const locale = getLocale(request)
    if (locale === i18n.defaultLocale) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(pathname, request.url))
    }
    // e.g. incoming request is /products
    // The new URL is now /en-US/products
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `/${locale}${pathname.startsWith('/') ? '' : '/'}${pathname}`,
        request.url
      )
    )
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'],
}
```